# negative binomial distribution vs geometric distributiion

Tags: probability

How can this question be geometric and also negative binomial.
In order to join a group Peter needs 9 invitations.The probability that he receives an invitation on any day is 0.8, independent of other days.

He joins as soon as he receives his 9 th invitation. Given that he joined on the 14 th day, find the probability that he receives his first invite on the first day.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this question be geometric and also negative binomial.

A negative binomial random variable, $X\sim\mathcal{NB}(r,q)$, is a count of successes occurring (at rate $q$) before $r$ failures.

A (zero-based) geometric random variable, $Y\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)$, is a count of failures before the first success, with success rate $p$.

Hence: $Y\sim\mathcal{NB}(1,1-p)$.   That is: A geomemtric distribution with parameter $p$ is a negative binomial distribution with parameters $1, 1-p$.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric distribution is a special case of the binomial negative distribution with parameter r=1.

To see why this is the reason, see how they come to be. The geometric distribution represents the number of tries needed to get a positive result in a binomial setting, while the negative binomial represents the number of tries needed to get an arbitrary number r of successes.

From here we can deduce what I claimed, and also that the negative binomial of parameter r corresponds to the sum of r independent identically distributed random variables with geometric distribution.

---

Let's try to solve your problem! Let $X_i$ denote the event 'Peter receives an invitation the ith day'. Then each $X_i\sim Bern(p=0.8)$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i\sim Bin(p=0.8,r=13)$ (note that $X_14$ is fixed to be true since Peter is guaranteed to have received an invitation the last day).

Let's use Bayes:

$P(X_1=1|\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8)=P(X_i=1)\cdot \frac{P(\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8|X_1=1)}{\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8}$

Note that $[\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8|X_1=1]\equiv [\sum_{i=2}^{13}X_i=7]\sim Bern(p=0.8,r=12)=7$.

Thus we know the distribution of each term in the Bayes equation, so we can directly substitute:

$P(X_1=1|\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8)=0.8\cdot \frac{{12\choose 7} (0.8)^{7}(1-0.8)^ {12-7}}{{13\choose 8} (0.8)^{8}(1-0.8)^ {13-8}}=\frac{8}{13}$

Note this result can be obtained in a more direct way using the following reasoning. The probability of receiving an invitation each day is equal, and we know that from days 1 to 13 he has received 8 invitations. Then the probability of getting an invitation the first day is equal to the number of combinations of 8 days between those 13 including the first between the total number of combinations of 8 days over 13:

$P(X_1=1|\sum_{i=1}^{13}X_i=8)=\frac{12 \choose 7}{13\choose 8}=\frac{8}{13}$.

So yeah, using the negative binomial or geometric here is not needed, and more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Thanks, am better now, but how is it  0.615?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: fully satisfied and seen my mistake.Greatiful.thanks